# Custom format for the standard deviation with siunitx?

Tags: siunitx

I have read the threads on this site but could not find a solution for my problem. I want to use `siunitx` to set my units including a standard deviation. For numbers given in years I have to use this format:

> 50,1 (SD: 11,1) years

Is there a way to achieve this with a reusable command?

Answer (score 1):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[separate-uncertainty=true]{siunitx}
\sisetup{output-decimal-marker={,}}

\newcommand\uncertaintyYears[2]{\SI{#1} (SD: #2) years}

\begin{document}
\uncertaintyYears{50,2}{11,1}
\uncertaintyYears{20.2}{6,3}
\uncertaintyYears{8,2}{2,05}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Of course this works but it doesn't format the number in the SD part with siunitx, maybe something like `\newcommand\uncertaintyYears[2]{\SI{#1} (SD: \num[some options here]{#2}) years}`?

Comment: @Marijn I am not too familiar with `siunitx` and creating custom commands with optional arguments, this is what I do in my documents as a relative novice to this. I would be interested in an alternative answer to grow my knowledge if you knew how to do this better please, this is just my basic method I would use

Comment: That is a nice solution, but indeed, i would have to redefine it for every unit. It would be nice if icould somehow use the standard \SI{1(2)}{\unit} syntax

Answer (score 0):

You can set up the uncertainty so that you achieve your desired output with the option `output-open-uncertainty` like this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{output-decimal-marker={,},
        output-open-uncertainty={\mathrm{(SD\colon}\ },     
        uncertainty-mode=full}
\DeclareSIUnit{\y}{years}

\begin{document}

\qty{50,1(11,1)}{\y}

\end{document}
```

With `uncertainty-mode=full` the decimal marker is displayed in the uncertainty term. Per default (mode: `compact`) the decimal marker will not be printed (see [code documentation](https://ctan.mc1.root.project-creative.net/macros/latex/contrib/siunitx/siunitx-code.pdf) page 12 and/or [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/165175/controlling-the-decimal-position-of-the-uncertainty-while-using-multi-part-units)).

A separate command as suggested before could also be adjusted to do the same with arbitrary units like this: `\newcommand{\qtySD}[3]{\num{#1}(SD: \num{#2})\,\unit{#3}}%`. Then the call would be `\qtySD{50,1}{11,1}{\y}`. This might come in handy, if one would also like to use the standard form of the uncertainty, although one could simply change back the option for a single quantity like this `\qty[output-open-uncertainty=(]{50,1(11,1)}{\y}`.